# Java Client for Binance API load big data on startup

Tags: java, caching, cryptography, binance

I am coding a java based desktop client connected to the binance API

The problem I am having is as follows:

I am trying to cache Candlestick data for every listed Asset on Binance.com (roughly 450 Coins). I need 200 Candlesticks per Timeframe for each asset.

Example:

- `Five_Minute` Timeframe get 200 Candles
- `Fifteen_Minute` Timeframe get 200 Candles

up to the monthly time frame. So basically 10 * 200 * 450 Assets.

I need to cache these data in order to be able to make calculations close to real time. But starting up the application while the data is being fetched takes ages.

What would be your approach?

---

I am using the Binance REST API for this.

Each `getCandlestickbars()` for a specific time frame and asset takes around 300ms, so I am ending up around 6 - 10 seconds per cache.

Sorry I am just coding a few month and learn as I go :)

Comment: Hi BitQueen and welcome. Please try and review / spell check your question before posting. I've made some changes, which you can view / change / rollback by clicking the word "edited" above my name / picture below your question. You may want to click that to see the markdown changes I made to your question.

Comment: The binance tag has 14 followers and 66 questions assigned to it. That's more than I expected, but it is not a huge amount either. It may take some time to get an answer because of that.

Answer (score 1):

you should multithread it yourself or call http request asynchronously (if your http lib supports it).